# Automatically advance date by one month

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula to automatically add a month to a date field once that day has passed.

So if cell A2 I enter `Oct 7`, I would like that date to change to `Nov 7` on October 8th, and continue to do that every month.

Is there a formula to do this? or a VBS script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a formula then you will need to either "Hard Code" the desired day, or reference another cell in which you put the day.

The "Hard Coded" day version:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+IF(DAY(TODAY())>7,1,0),7)
```

Where, both `7`s are the day of the month desired.

One can replace the `7`s with a cell reference in which the day is put.

Comment: could I reference a date from a specific cell to make it think that today was whichever date I chose?  so say I enter 10/1/2016 in cell F2, can I make it reference that as the date it uses to adjust advancing the month in your other formula?

Comment: That formula works perfectly though.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, just replace the `7`s with `Day(F2)`.  Please mark the answer as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: That just changes the date in my original block.  I want it to think that todays date is whatever I put in block F2.  so say today is 10/17, the date of 10/16 has already moved to 11/16 per your first formula.  I want to be able to put 10/18 in F2 and have the 10/17 date advance to 11/17, even though it isn't actually the 18th of October.

Comment: Ah, then change all the Today() to F2

Comment: Perfect.  Exactly what I was looking for.